# Find nested matching HTML tags in Java

Tags: java, html, tags, jsoup

I´m working with a valid HTML String (parsed with jsoup, so all tags have closing tags and it`s well formed) in Java, and I need to find the content of a given tag name , for example
, working with the following String:

```
<p> hi! </p>
<p> hi again! </p>
<h1> foo </h1>
<p> bye! </p>
```

The results I expect, given the tag 'p' are:

```
1)<p> hi! </p>
2)<p> hi again! </p>
3)<p> bye! </p>
```

I´ve acomplished this by simply using the apache.commons.lang library with the method
StringUtils.substringsBetween(String html, String "opentag" , String "endtag") which would return an array of String with the desired results. However when I search for a tag that has the exact same tag nested within ( a common example is div) I will get the wrong results (I understand why)

For example, working with ...

```
<div>
 <p> hey there </p>
 <div>  
  <div>
   <p> asd </p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I would expect 3 results:
1)

```
<div>
 <p> hey there </p>
 <div>  
  <div>
   <p> asd </p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

2)

```
<div>  
 <div>
  <p> asd </p>
 </div>
</div>
```

3)

```
<div>
 <p> asd </p>
</div>
```

However I get one (I know its because of how the occurrences of the tag appear in the String) I just dont know how to solve it. I have been struggling with it for 2 weeks now, I have tried with regex with no succes at all, I´ve also tried spliting the html String into an array of lines but failed too.

How would you approach this problem? I already know that there are tons of libraries that do this for you with methods such as jsoup's getAllElementsByTag(tagName) but I want to do it myself. Any hints are appreciated!

Comment: What's the point of looking at individual start and end tags if (1) you know the HTML is valid and (2) there are far saner (read: DOM) APIs for working with HTML? To do this correctly, you're effectively going to re-implement some pieces of an HTML parser.

Comment: How refreshing! An HTML parsing question which does not ask for the use of regexes :p

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794108/gettings-substrings-between-tags

Comment: not sure why you want to do it yourself. Just use jsoup...

Comment: Also I wish folks would not put restrictions like "without using libraries" at the end of long questions. That really should be at the front since it is critical information that completely changes the answer.

Comment: @Gus How does forbidding the use of libraries being at the end of the question changes the answer? Why would you answer a question without reading it through?

Comment: It causes the reader (who is thinking **while** they are reading) to spend lots of brain cycles thinking how to answer your question only to discover that they have to throw out everything they were thinking and start over. Most people don't suspend all thought while reading. And information at the end is the most likely to be missed... two people (that I saw) answered your question with how to use jsoup and then deleted their answer (one of them being me). Puting key information at the very end just wastes people's time and effort.

Comment: To put it another way, one *expects* "here's my problem, here's what I've tried" not "here's a problem, here's something I tried, here's the rest of the problem"

Comment: @Gus fair enough , I'll keep that in mind next time, still it's strange for someone who cares so much about brain cycles to answer a question they have not even finished reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to make heavy use of tokenization and recursion to solve this issue.  Essentially, every time a new tag opens (say, `<div>`), you launch through your processing again.

Consider something like the following:

```
ArrayList<String> elements = new ArrayList<String>();
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(html);

public String populateDivContents(String buildingString) {

    while(scanner.hasNext()) {

        //Get the next token
        String next = scanner.next();

        //If it's a <div>, call recursively
        if(next.equalsIgnoreCase("<div>")) {
            buildingString = buildingString + populateDivContents(next);
        }

        //If we've hit a closing tag, add our built String to the elements
        else if(next.equalsIgnoreCase("</div>") {
            buildingString = buildingString + next;
            elements.add(buildingString);
            return buildingString;
        }

        //Otherwise, simply add the text to our String and keep going
        else {
            buildingString = buildingString + next;
        }
    }
}
```

This is a very rough sketch and has some issues, especially if your tags are not separated by new lines or spaces from their content (as they are in your examples).  It also assumes the HTML is well-formed, as you say.  But it's enough to get the idea across.  The `ArrayList<String>` declared will contain all `<div>` tags and their contents.

Comment: I'll try to work with this ideas, thanks a lot for your time and insight!

Answer (score 1):

A standard approach for this is to use a stack. I.e., when you encounter an opening tag, you dump in on a stack, and whenever you encounter a closing tag, you pop the topmost item. If the String is indeed well-formed, all closing tags should pop a matching opening tag. From there, it should be a piece of cake to figure out how get to the inner pair's content.

Comment: perhaps dump the position at which you found it onto the stack, and then substring using what you pop and your current position. The hard part is recognizing all the legal variants such as <div> < div> <div > <div class="spiffy"> etc.

Comment: @Gus Yes, for example. You could also just record everything from the last opening tag and declare it your result if you find </p>. But you are absolutely right about the variants. It definitely gets harder with named elements.

Answer (score 0):

`TagSoup` or `Jsoup` will be the one you are looking for:)